# Getting all types from an assembly derived from a base class

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to examine the contents of an assembly and find all classes in it that are directly or indirectly derived from Windows.Forms.UserControl.

I am doing this:

```
Assembly dll = Assembly.LoadFrom(filename);
var types = dll.GetTypes().Where(x => x.BaseType == typeof(UserControl));
```

But it is giving an empty list because none of the classes directly extend UserControl. I don't know enough about reflection to do it quickly, and I'd rather not write a recursive function if I don't have to.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should use [`Type.IsSubclassOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof.aspx) this instead:

```
var types = dll.GetTypes().Where(x => x.IsSubclassOf(typeof(UserControl)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
    var assembly = Assembly.Load(filename);
    var types = assembly.GetTypes().Where((type) => typeof(UserControl).IsAssignableFrom(type));
```