# Get class names of all entities that inherit from a base entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance

Assuming i have a base entity class:

```
public abstract partial class Person
    {
        public Person()
        {
        }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }


    }
```

and i have multiple entities that inherit from that entity e.g:

```
public partial class Customer : Person
{
    public Customer()
    {
    }

    public int CustomerStatusId { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }

}
```

and a few more entities that inherit from the `Person` class.

is there a way i can get all the Entities class names that inherit from the `Person` class?
i would like to display those in a `select` box, to create a generic `AddUser` method.

Comment: Take a look at this post, I think this is what you need:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480691/getting-all-types-from-an-assembly-derived-from-a-base-class

Comment: I *assume* you only want to know about implementations within (the current assembly/a limited set of assemblies) because, of course, this being a public class there could be an infinite number of inheriting classes.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var names = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => baseType.IsAssignableFrom(t)).Select(t => t.Name);
```

Try something like the above to get just the names.

Use the following answer for reference [How to find all the types in an Assembly that Inherit from a Specific Type C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268397/how-to-find-all-the-types-in-an-assembly-that-inherit-from-a-specific-type-c-sha)

Comment: This should do it but it appears you have a misplaced return statement.

Comment: I agree. I have updated

Answer (score 1):

You need to use reflections:

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Assembly a = typeof(Program).Assembly;

        var types = a.GetTypes().Where(i=>i.IsSubclassOf(typeof(T)));

        foreach(var i in types)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}

public class T {  }
public class TT : T {  }
public class TTT : T {  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Reflection is the easiest way to go (as suggested in other answers).

Yet (since you tagged the question with `entity-framework` and you mentioned `Entities`) in case your intent is to get list of derived types that **exists in the database** (to fill up a lookup) you can try this:

```
var typeNames = context.Set<Person>()
                       .ToList()
                       .Select(x => x.GetType().Name)
                       .Distinct();
```

Comment: Interesting. i usually try to avoid using reflection, but i wonder which one would be more "costly", my guess would be that another db call would be more then the reflection one.

Comment: if you mean "costly" in terms of performance, Reflection would probably be much faster, especially if your table contains many `Person`. however, if you require your drop-down list to only contain types that *already exists* in the database, i guess you would have to use that solution.